# ASP.NET MVC: calling a controller method from view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm implementing paging on an ASP.NET MVC view, and I want to call a method in the controller from the view.

Code in the view:

```
<a href="<%= Url.Action("Search", 
            new { page = NextPage(Request["exactPage"])).ToString()}) %>">
```

Controller method:

```
public string NextPage(string currentPage)
{
     return (int.Parse(currentPage) +  1).ToString();
}
```

How can I call the NextPage method from the view?

thanks!

Comment: @Alice in wonderland: You can format text as code by indenting it by 4 spaces (select and press Ctrl+K). This will allow you to use special characters like `<` without problems.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the number of the current page, could you not just render links where the *page* value = *current page* plus/minus 1 for the previous and next links?  You don't really need the view to ask the controller what the next/previous page number is.  That information can be derived by the view based on the value of the current page index.

**EDIT:** I suggest that the controller passes an additional value to the view indicating the total number of pages available.  The view can then compare this value against the current page number to determine whether to display the *next* link.

Comment: Yes, but then you will keep going so if the last page is 3, the next page will keep going up to 100 or whatever.  So I want it to stay where it is when it reaches the last page...which is logic I'd prefer to put in a method...

Comment: Something like: <%(if (Request["exactPage"] < TotalPage)) {%> <a href="<%=Url.Action("Search", new { exactPage = int.Parse(Request["exactPage"]) + 1).ToString}) %>"> <%}%> (sorry can't work out how to format code) Seems a bit longwinded for a webpage...

Comment: @Alice in wonderland: You could wrap this logic up in a HTML helper method to make your view code more readable.  Something like: Html.RenderNextPageLink(currentPage, totalPages)

Answer (score 2):

I forget where it came from.  Perhaps someone could post the link as a comment here.

I think this is code complete.

I have this as a project;

MvcPaging;

**IPagedList**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MvcPaging
{
    public interface IPagedList<T> : IList<T>
    {
        int PageCount { get; }
        int TotalItemCount { get; }
        int PageIndex { get; }
        int PageNumber { get; }
        int PageSize { get; }
        bool HasPreviousPage { get; }
        bool HasNextPage { get; }
        bool IsFirstPage { get; }
        bool IsLastPage { get; }
    }
}
```

**PagedList**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using MvcPaging;

namespace MvcPaging
{
    public class PagedList<T> : List<T>, IPagedList<T>
    {
        public PagedList(IEnumerable<T> source, int index, int pageSize)
            : this(source, index, pageSize, null)
        {
        }

        public PagedList(IEnumerable<T> source, int index, int pageSize, int? totalCount)
        {
            Initialize(source.AsQueryable(), index, pageSize, totalCount);
        }

        public PagedList(IQueryable<T> source, int index, int pageSize)
            : this(source, index, pageSize, null)
        {
        }

        public PagedList(IQueryable<T> source, int index, int pageSize, int? totalCount)
        {
            Initialize(source, index, pageSize, totalCount);
        }

        #region IPagedList Members

        public int PageCount { get; private set; }
        public int TotalItemCount { get; private set; }
        public int PageIndex { get; private set; }
        public int PageNumber { get { return PageIndex + 1; } }
        public int PageSize { get; private set; }
        public bool HasPreviousPage { get; private set; }
        public bool HasNextPage { get; private set; }
        public bool IsFirstPage { get; private set; }
        public bool IsLastPage { get; private set; }

        #endregion

        protected void Initialize(IQueryable<T> source, int index, int pageSize, int? totalCount)
        {
            //### argument checking
            if (index < 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("PageIndex cannot be below 0.");
            }
            if (pageSize < 1)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("PageSize cannot be less than 1.");
            }

            //### set source to blank list if source is null to prevent exceptions
            if (source == null)
            {
                source = new List<T>().AsQueryable();
            }

            //### set properties
            if (!totalCount.HasValue)
            {
                TotalItemCount = source.Count();
            }
            PageSize = pageSize;
            PageIndex = index;
            if (TotalItemCount > 0)
            {
                PageCount = (int)Math.Ceiling(TotalItemCount / (double)PageSize);
            }
            else
            {
                PageCount = 0;
            }
            HasPreviousPage = (PageIndex > 0);
            HasNextPage = (PageIndex < (PageCount - 1));
            IsFirstPage = (PageIndex <= 0);
            IsLastPage = (PageIndex >= (PageCount - 1));

            //### add items to internal list
            if (TotalItemCount > 0)
            {
                AddRange(source.Skip((index) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Pager**

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace MvcPaging
{
    public class Pager
    {
        private ViewContext viewContext;
        private readonly int pageSize;
        private readonly int currentPage;
        private readonly int totalItemCount;
        private readonly RouteValueDictionary linkWithoutPageValuesDictionary;

        public Pager(ViewContext viewContext, int pageSize, int currentPage, int totalItemCount, RouteValueDictionary valuesDictionary)
        {
            this.viewContext = viewContext;
            this.pageSize = pageSize;
            this.currentPage = currentPage;
            this.totalItemCount = totalItemCount;
            this.linkWithoutPageValuesDictionary = valuesDictionary;
        }

        public string RenderHtml()
        {
            int pageCount = (int)Math.Ceiling(this.totalItemCount / (double)this.pageSize);
            int nrOfPagesToDisplay = 10;

            var sb = new StringBuilder();

            // Previous
            if (this.currentPage > 1)
            {
                sb.Append(GeneratePageLink("Previous", this.currentPage - 1));
            }
            else
            {
                sb.Append("<span class=\"disabled\">Previous</span>");
            }

            int start = 1;
            int end = pageCount;

            if (pageCount > nrOfPagesToDisplay)
            {
                int middle = (int)Math.Ceiling(nrOfPagesToDisplay / 2d) - 1;
                int below = (this.currentPage - middle);
                int above = (this.currentPage + middle);

                if (below < 4)
                {
                    above = nrOfPagesToDisplay;
                    below = 1;
                }
                else if (above > (pageCount - 4))
                {
                    above = pageCount;
                    below = (pageCount - nrOfPagesToDisplay);
                }

                start = below;
                end = above;
            }

            if (start > 3)
            {
                sb.Append(GeneratePageLink("1", 1));
                sb.Append(GeneratePageLink("2", 2));
                sb.Append("...");
            }
            for (int i = start; i <= end; i++)
            {
                if (i == this.currentPage)
                {
                    sb.AppendFormat("<span class=\"current\">{0}</span>", i);
                }
                else
                {
                    sb.Append(GeneratePageLink(i.ToString(), i));
                }
            }
            if (end < (pageCount - 3))
            {
                sb.Append("...");
                sb.Append(GeneratePageLink((pageCount - 1).ToString(), pageCount - 1));
                sb.Append(GeneratePageLink(pageCount.ToString(), pageCount));
            }

            // Next
            if (this.currentPage < pageCount)
            {
                sb.Append(GeneratePageLink("Next", (this.currentPage + 1)));
            }
            else
            {
                sb.Append("<span class=\"disabled\">Next</span>");
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }

        private string GeneratePageLink(string linkText, int pageNumber)
        {
            var pageLinkValueDictionary = new RouteValueDictionary(this.linkWithoutPageValuesDictionary);
            pageLinkValueDictionary.Add("page", pageNumber);
            //var virtualPathData = this.viewContext.RouteData.Route.GetVirtualPath(this.viewContext, pageLinkValueDictionary);
            var virtualPathData = RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPath(this.viewContext.RequestContext, pageLinkValueDictionary);

            if (virtualPathData != null)
            {
                string linkFormat = "<a href=\"{0}\">{1}</a>";
                return String.Format(linkFormat, virtualPathData.VirtualPath, linkText);
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**PagingExtensions**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;
using MvcPaging;

namespace MvcPaging
{
    public static class PagingExtensions
    {
        public static string Pager(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, int pageSize, int currentPage, int totalItemCount)
        {
            return Pager(htmlHelper, pageSize, currentPage, totalItemCount, null, null);
        }

        public static string Pager(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, int pageSize, int currentPage, int totalItemCount, string actionName)
        {
            return Pager(htmlHelper, pageSize, currentPage, totalItemCount, actionName, null);
        }

        public static string Pager(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, int pageSize, int currentPage, int totalItemCount, object values)
        {
            return Pager(htmlHelper, pageSize, currentPage, totalItemCount, null, new RouteValueDictionary(values));
        }

        public static string Pager(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, int pageSize, int currentPage, int totalItemCount, string actionName, object values)
        {
            return Pager(htmlHelper, pageSize, currentPage, totalItemCount, actionName, new RouteValueDictionary(values));
        }

        public static string Pager(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, int pageSize, int currentPage, int totalItemCount, RouteValueDictionary valuesDictionary)
        {
            return Pager(htmlHelper, pageSize, currentPage, totalItemCount, null, valuesDictionary);
        }

        public static string Pager(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, int pageSize, int currentPage, int totalItemCount, string actionName, RouteValueDictionary valuesDictionary)
        {
            if (valuesDictionary == null)
            {
                valuesDictionary = new RouteValueDictionary();
            }
            if (actionName != null)
            {
                if (valuesDictionary.ContainsKey("action"))
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("The valuesDictionary already contains an action.", "actionName");
                }
                valuesDictionary.Add("action", actionName);
            }
            var pager = new Pager(htmlHelper.ViewContext, pageSize, currentPage, totalItemCount, valuesDictionary);
            return pager.RenderHtml();
        }

        public static IPagedList<T> ToPagedList<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
        {
            return new PagedList<T>(source, pageIndex, pageSize);
        }

        public static IPagedList<T> ToPagedList<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize, int totalCount)
        {
            return new PagedList<T>(source, pageIndex, pageSize, totalCount);
        }

        public static IPagedList<T> ToPagedList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
        {
            return new PagedList<T>(source, pageIndex, pageSize);
        }

        public static IPagedList<T> ToPagedList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize, int totalCount)
        {
            return new PagedList<T>(source, pageIndex, pageSize, totalCount);
        }
    }
}
```

Then in my Controller;

```
public class IndexArticlesFormViewModel
{
    public IPagedList<Article> articles {get; set;}
    public IQueryable<string> userTags { get; set; }
    public string tag {get; set;}
}


    public ActionResult SearchResults(int? page, string tag)
    {
        IndexArticlesFormViewModel fvm = new IndexArticlesFormViewModel();
        fvm.articles = ar.Search(tag).ToPagedList(page.HasValue ? page.Value - 1 : 0, 8);
        fvm.tag = tag;

        return View(fvm);
    }

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult SearchResults(int? page, string tag, FormCollection collection)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(collection["txtSearch"]))
            return RedirectToAction("SearchResults", new {page = 1, tag = collection["txtSearch"] });

        return RedirectToAction("SearchResults", new { page = page, searchTerm = tag });
    }
```

And then the View;

```
<div class="pager">
    <%= Html.Pager(ViewData.Model.articles.PageSize, ViewData.Model.articles.PageNumber, ViewData.Model.articles.TotalItemCount, new { tag = Model.tag })%>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @Jason.  I've actually found several references to this code and can hoestly not remember where it came from.  Works great though

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested, an HtmlHelper might be appropriate here, but if you do want to call a static method on some other class you can just add a namespace import to the top of your View.

```
<%@ Import Namespace="YOURCONTROLLERNAMESPACE"%>
```