# Beginner to MVC 4: Need to call methods from external or another class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am very new to MVC 4. I am having a scenario where i need to define a set of methods in seperate class and call all those methods in an controller. so that i could handle  functionality different from view.

Below are samples of my code.... Please review.

i have added an new class file under controller and defined the methods as below:

```
 public void Convert(ConvertFileOutputType outputType, FileInfo inFile, DirectoryInfo        outFolder, int timeout,
        int topMargin, int bottomMargin, int leftMargin, int rightMargin)
    {
       switch (outputType)
        {
            case ConvertFileOutputType.Pdf:
                break;
            default: break;
            // throw new    ConvertFileException(Properties.Resources.OutputTypeNotSupportedWordPerfect);
        }
        if (converter == null)
        {
            //converter.LicenseKey = "";
            converter = new PdfConverter();
            converter.LicenseKey = "";
            converter.PdfDocumentOptions.LiveUrlsEnabled = false;
            converter.PdfDocumentOptions.PdfPageSize = PdfPageSize.Letter;
            converter.PdfDocumentOptions.TopMargin = topMargin;
            converter.PdfDocumentOptions.BottomMargin = bottomMargin;
            converter.PdfDocumentOptions.LeftMargin = leftMargin;
            converter.PdfDocumentOptions.RightMargin = rightMargin;
            converter.AvoidImageBreak = true;
        }
        converter.PdfDocumentInfo.AuthorName = "FileConvert";
        converter.PdfDocumentInfo.Title = inFile.Name;
        converter.PdfDocumentInfo.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
        converter.SavePdfFromHtmlFileToFile(inFile.FullName, outFolder + "\\" + inFile.Name + ".pdf");
    }
```

And i want to call this above method in an controller method....
i have blindly written code as....

```
  public string UploadAsPDF(HttpPostedFileBase fileData)
     {
         var fileName = this.Server.MapPath("~/uploads/" +     System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileData.FileName));
         fileData.SaveAs(fileName);


        Convert(outputType, inFile,outFolder,timeout, topMargin, bottomMargin, leftMargin, rightMargin);

         return "OK"; 
     }
```

whenever i tried to build its a type is being used as method
Please advice....

Comment: You are passing the method name as arguement to the `Convert` method, passed an object of type `ConvertFileOutputType` instead.

Comment: Sorry! it was an edit mistake. i will be sending a set of parameters as like filename,size,src,dest and dimension for pdf file generation

Comment: Please have a look at:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15398177/asp-net-mvc-calling-a-method-from-a-view

is that what you want?

Comment: Can you show exactly what you're passing to the `Convert` method?

Comment: @WannaCSharp, i have updated the edits..please advise

Comment: Try calling your `Convert` method this way `NameOfClassObject.Convert`

Comment: @wannaCSharp this will only work if it's **static**

Comment: @WannaCSharp.. thank for your supports.... :) finally it worked!!!

Comment: @christiandev I said class object not the class itself.

Comment: @WannaCSharp, you meant name of the variable for the instantiated object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the `Convert` method is in a class called `Converters`, you would need to `instantiate` the class, and then call `Convert`....

```
public Converters {
   public void Convert(...);
}
```

You will then use like this...

```
public string UploadAsPDF(HttpPostedFileBase fileData)
     {
         var fileName = this.Server.MapPath("~/uploads/" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileData.FileName));
         fileData.SaveAs(fileName);


        var converters = new Converters();
        converters.Convert(outputType, inFile,outFolder,timeout, 
                           topMargin, bottomMargin, leftMargin, rightMargin);

         return "OK"; 
     }
```