# Razor C# Create function / use it in another file

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I created a function in one file func.cshtml like this.

```
@functions {
    int sum(a, b)
    {
        return a+b;
    }
}
```

and I want to use this function in another file.

There are several links I can find, but they are for an older version and won't work for what I want to do.

Comment: That answer is not working.
I also left a comment there.
I have this error.
CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Functions.AgoDateString()'

Comment: Did you declare it in a file named `Functions.cshtml`, or in `func.cshtml` as in this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should move that function from the view file into a .cs file, then call it from views that need it.

Comment: hi @h2015, thanks for your answer, when I create the project from razor framework option, it just creates the .cshtml files, after I create the code in .cs file how can I use it on .cshtml file?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15398249/4678104

Comment: Thanks your answer is working fine. I was able to make it working.

Comment: Maybe upvote the original answer also :)