# How to call a method inside a class in view without referencing the class itself?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I currently have this code.

```
public static class User
{
    public static string GetUserName()
    {
        return Username;
    }
}
```

I want to call in view `@GetUserName()`, not `User.GetUserName();`

Is it possible to call a method inside a class in view MVC without referencing the class itself?

Comment: Encouragement for the OP: I don't know why this question has attracted 4 downvotes. You've been clear about you want to achieve. It's possible that those votes indicate disagreement about the merit of that goal, and the question could be improved by explaining *why* you feel this is worth trying to achieve, but that's all.

Answer (score 2):

You *can* do this with a `using static` directive, although I'd personally be concerned about the readability:

```
@using static User
...
<p>The user name is: @GetUserName()</p>
```

If `User` is in a different namespace, you'd need this instead:

```
@using static WhateverNamespace.User
```

To repeat, I'd be very cautious about using this in terms of the readability... but it should *work* with no issues.

You could also add extension methods, although that isn't quite as neat. For example, my test app for this uses Razor pages, so I've got an `IRazorPage` extension method:

```
namespace YourNamespace
{
    public static class PageExtensions
    {
        public static string GetUserName(this IRazorPage view) => User.GetUserName();
    }
}
```

Due to the way extension methods are looked up, you then need:

```
<p>The user name is: @this.GetUserName()</p>
```

The `this.` is a little ugly, but at least you don't need to remember the class name.

Comment: It doesn't have to be static, you can just directly reference the namespace location and class name as noted in the question itself.

Comment: @TravisJ: I don't know what you mean. If you don't use `using static` you can't just write `@GetUserName()`, you'd have to write `@User.GetUserName()`, which is what the OP wants to avoid. I don't understand what you're suggesting.

Comment: It seemed the point was to avoid the namespace and class name altogether. Fair enough though, I take your point that this is one possibility to call the method name without using the class name in the same line.

Comment: @TravisJ: I'd assumed that the OP wanted to be able to do this with potentially multiple methods or multiple times within the same view - a single `using static` directive would achieve that. I'll write an extra option with extension methods though.

Comment: Iam trying this @using static Mynamespace not available
It get error static keyword which framework this 
Iam using 4.5.1

Comment: @testedhanes: You need support for C# 6, basically - it's a C# 6 feature. If I were you I'd upgrade to a more recent framework (and potentially IDE) version.

Answer (score 1):

Just using `@GetUserName()` wont work by default, as you state. The [normal way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15398249/1026459) to do this is to reference the class name and then use `User.GetUserName();`. You clearly are already aware of that.

However, that doesn't mean part of this isn't possible. It shouldn't be done frivolously though. In order to directly call methods inside of your views you need to add them to your Views folder's `web.config` file. Not the global one mind you, specifically the one in the views folder.

Inside of that file, you should find the `namespace` element. This is where you can add your namespace reference to be able to directly call this method from your views.

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    ...
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />

        <!-- add the namespace containing static class User here -->
        <add namespace="YourNamespace" />  

      </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Once this is done, and recompiled, you will be able to use `@User.GetUserName()` from the `User` class in `YourNamespace` in any view inside of that Views folder. If you are using areas, then you will need to do this for each view folder per area.

From my experience this use has been in extensions. Unfortunately it will not completely remove the need to use `@User`, however it will remove the need to always be referencing the namespace when you do access that class.

Comment: So adding a namespace that's actually a class implicitly uses `using static` instead of just `using`? Interesting.

Comment: I've just tried this for the sake of interest, and it didn't work: "CS0138: A 'using namespace' directive can only be applied to namespaces; 'User' is a type not a namespace. Consider a 'using static' directive instead". It showed the generated code, which just had `using YourNamespace.User;` rather than `using static YourNamespace.User;`. That was using regular ASP.NET MVC (not Core). Does this definitely work for some specific version?

Comment: @DaisyShipton - I had included the class name as part of the namespace in the suggestion, so in that regard it perhaps showed up as not working. This is mainly used for expansion in my projects, however, it does not appear that using the method name without actually referencing the class name is possible.

Comment: YourNamespace.User is not working
Iam declare in web.config 
But still Without class declare is not possible tell me how to do it

Comment: @testedhanes - It should be just YourNamespace inside of the web.config, and then `User.GetUserName()` should work in any associated view. Make sure the web.config file that you use is the one in the views folder, and not the one for the overall project.