# asp.net MVC 5 Using javascript AJAX to call controller function

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've started learning the .NET Framework MVC 5 pattern. I've gone through the Microsoft tutorial "Getting Started with Entity Framework 6 Code First using MVC 5" and have a working CRUD application.

One of the features of my app is the ability to drag and drop objects around the screen and save the position  in SQL (server side), so the position is persisted. I work out where the object has been dropped in a JavaScript function so I need to save the position to SQL from within this JavaScript function. I have this working, using an AJAX call to a function in my controller:

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "/Asset/UpdatePosition",
        data: { 'ID': offset[2], 'left': event.clientX + parseInt(offset[0], 10), 'top': event.clientY + parseInt(offset[1], 10)},
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (result) {

        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert(result);
        }
    });


 public ActionResult UpdatePosition(int Id, int left, int top)
    {
        var theAsset = db.Assets.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == Id);
        theAsset.MapPositionLeft = left;
        theAsset.MapPositionTop = top;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return Json("success", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

My question is I *can* do this, but *should* I. It feels like a hack and there is no point me learning MVC if I'm going to start breaking the architectural rules on day one. I know I could persist the data client side, but let's say I need the data server side for some reason. Is there a "proper" way to update server side data from JavaScript, or is what I'm doing actually sound ?
Martin

Edit:
To clarify why I'm asking , I originally just called the UpdatePosition function from my view directly like :
[ASP.Net MVC: Calling a method from a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15398177/asp-net-mvc-calling-a-method-from-a-view)
but one of the comments points out that "If you need to call controller from View - you are doing something wrong. Time for refactoring." So I know that approach was wrong - but because I'm a noob at MVC I have no idea if my ajax call above is any better.

Comment: Looks fine, is there a specific crux you are thinking about here? You could consider using a frontend js framework, but for small apps it might not be worth the hassle of wiring it up.

Comment: If I'm correct you're hitting the database for every single reposition, right?

Comment: What makes you think its a hack? Making an ajax call to update the database is the only way to do it using javascript is you ant to stay in the same page

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with it ...