# Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference with ViewBag and List

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, view, viewbag

I can't seem to find a way around this and I'm thinking I'm just taking the wrong approach, but what would the right one be?

My controller has a method like so:

```
        public List<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem> GetSupplierAvg(string cityname, string actualproduct)
    {
        var gsa = db.Database.SqlQuery<string>("select distinct SupplierAvg from OPIS_Price_import where City=@cn and ActualProduct=@ap", 
            new SqlParameter("@cn", cityname), new SqlParameter("@ap", actualproduct));
        var SupplierAvgList = new List<SelectListItem>();
        foreach (var thing in gsa)
        {
            SupplierAvgList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = thing, Selected = false, Value = thing });
        }

        ViewBag.SupplierAvgList = SupplierAvgList;
        return ViewBag.SupplierAvgList;
    }
```

and my View is trying to call it like this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("SupplierAvgList", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.SupplierAvgList(item.CityName,thing))
```

But perhaps that's not the way this is supposed to work. Any insight would be truly appreciated.

Comment: `(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.SupplierAvgList(item.CityName,thing)` looks strange. Is `ViewBag.SupplierAvgList` a method? Try to check if ViewBag.SupplierAvgList is not null at the moment of page render, also on get/post requests

Comment: @Html.DropDownList("SupplierAvgList", new SelectList(ViewBag.SupplierAvgList, "Value" , "Text"))

Comment: @NaDeRStar that throws a "Value cannot be Null" error. I don't see how it can be null if it's making a call to my method which definitely is returning data.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not working because of the wrong call of the list. You are trying to call `SupplierAvgList` like a method, but this is a field (that also should be checked it's not null). Also guess you are trying to call `GetSupplierAvg` method with some  parameters. If so, then you have to call it using API or call it like another page (binded with action `GetSupplierAvg`), for example:

```
@Html.ActionLink("link text", "GetSupplierAvg", "controllerName", new { cityname = item.CityName, actualproduct = thing  }, null)
```

UPDATED

You can try the way below.
Call method from your view and pass this value to your dropdown list:

```
@{
    var dropDownData = ((YourController)this.ViewContext.Controller).GetSupplierAvg(item.CityName, thing);
}
@Html.DropDownList("SupplierAvgList", dropDownData);
```

P.S.
[ASP.Net MVC: Calling a method from a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15398177/asp-net-mvc-calling-a-method-from-a-view)

Comment: That would work if I needed to use a link to populate the page but I need the page to populate the dropdownlist at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You must change your return type from list to Action Result and should return a View.

```
 public ActionResult GetSupplierAvg(string cityname, string 
 actualproduct)
 {
    var gsa = db.Database.SqlQuery<string>("select distinct SupplierAvg from 
               OPIS_Price_import where City=@cn and ActualProduct=@ap", 
    new SqlParameter("@cn", cityname), new SqlParameter("@ap", actualproduct));
    var SupplierAvgList = new List<SelectListItem>();
    foreach (var thing in gsa)
    {
        SupplierAvgList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = thing, Selected = false, 
        Value = thing });
    }

    ViewBag.SupplierAvgList = SupplierAvgList;
    return View;
 }
```

Then in HTML , should write like ,

```
@{
var list = "Select Option";
if(@ViewBag.SupplierAvgList!=null)
{
  list = @ViewBag.SupplierAvgList;
}
}

// Your DropDown code here.
```