# How to retrieve an object property inside a view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an index method in a controller which looks like this :

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var object = _ObjectService.GetAll();
        return View(object);
    }
```

Which give me a list of object with those properties :

```
public class Object : EntityWithNameAndId
{
    public virtual Site Site { get; set; }
    public virtual List<User> Users { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Planning> Plannings { get; set; }
    public virtual Guid IdPilote { get; set; }
}
```

Now in my Index() view, i want to get the User who's related to the IdPilote id and display its name.

I tried something like this, thanks to this topic [ASP.Net MVC: Calling a method from a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15398177/asp-net-mvc-calling-a-method-from-a-view) :

```
@model List<MyClass.Models.Promotion>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <td>@item.Site.Name</td>

   @{ 
       var id = item.IdPilote;

       //Here Interface and Service are folders
       var user = MyDAL.Interface.Service.IUserService.Get(id);
    }

    <td>
        //This is where i try to display my User name, 
        //that i get dynamically using the idPilote for each User in list
    </td>
}
```

But Get(id) is not recognize as a valid method..

```
public interface IUserService : IDisposable
{
    User Get(Guid id);
}

public class UserService : IUserService
{
    private MyContext context;

    public UserService(MyContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public User Get(Guid id)
    {
        return context.User.Where(w => w.Id == id).SingleOrDefault();
    }
}
```

So what's the best way to get my User object inside my view, since i only get an Id ?

Should i create a new list, using the first one, in my Index method (where i can call IUserInterface.Get()) or is there a better way to do it ?

Comment: In a normal MVC application, you pass something called ViewModel between the Controller and View. You shouldn't call Repository/Service in the view.

Comment: I do have ViewModels but my Index view @model is a List<MyClass.Models.Object>. I'll edit my post

Comment: create separate viewmodel for view better to not used db entity direct in your view, because it might possible you use different validation or use `data-annotations` so bind your object to viewmodel and pass to view

Answer (score 0):

Make it worked by creating a new list and a specific ViewModel, as suggested :

```
public class IndexObjectViewModel : EntityWithNameAndId
{
    public virtual Site Site { get; set; }
    public virtual List<User> Users { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Planning> Plannings { get; set; }

    //To store User instead of its Id
    public virtual User Pilote { get; set; }
}
```

Now Index() looks like this :

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var objects = _IObjectService.GetAll();
    ViewBag.NotPromoExist = false;

    var indexObj = new List<IndexObjectViewModel>();           

    foreach (var p in objects)
    {
        var indexModel = new IndexObjectViewModel();

        indexModel.Id = p.Id;
        indexModel.Name = p.Name;
        indexModel.Site = p.Site;
        indexModel.Users = p.Users;
        indexModel.Plannings = p.Plannings;
        indexModel.Pilote = _IUserService.Get(p.IdPilote);

        indexObj.Add(indexModel);
    }

    return View(indexObj);
}
```

Everything is done in the controller now. Not sure if it's the best way to do it though..