# Call controller methods inside View

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a View and want to execute some controller methods inside of it.

> First method adds options inside select tag;
>
> Second method bound to the button executes process i need;

I tried a lot of options from google, but it does not let me even try them. It shows me `Unterminated string literal.` no matter what i try to do with it.

[how looks the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6OKm.png)

Simply it looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>Choose language to upload .html files</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form">
    <div>
        <h1>Choose language to upload .html files</h1>
        <select>
            /*After page is loaded, method from a controller will add options*/
        </select>
    </div>
    <button>Start</button> /*Another method from a controller will be bound to this button*/
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.Net MVC: Calling a method from a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15398177/asp-net-mvc-calling-a-method-from-a-view)

Comment: @KevinLamb i tried, it shows me the error i mentiond in the topic.

Comment: Can you show the way you're calling the methods in your view?

Comment: @KevinLamb added screenshot

Comment: Is there any reason you need location.href?

Comment: @JamesS i found this solution on stackoverflow, i don't know if i need something or not, could you please be more specific?

Comment: @JimmyOcha `@Url.Action("", "")` i'm presuming returns a view so you don't need `location.href`. If you just have the `@Url.Action("", "")` inside the onclick. I don't think it should break

Answer (score 0):

Rename your file extension from `.html` to `.cshtml`. Currently, what you're seeing is VS Code's JavaScript error for a regular html file. Once you change the file extension it will recognize that your file is a Razor view.

Another option is to set the language based settings of the file in VS Code to the appropriate language. You can do this by opening the `pub.cshtml_virtual.html` file and the language setting will be at the bottom right of VS Code.

Currently, the `pub.cshtml_virtual.html` file will be set to `HTML`:

[image: Image of html option]

click `HTML` to change it to `aspnetcorerazor` (might need an extension to get the option):

[image]

Comment: In the screenshot you provided, the file name is `pub.cshtml_virtual.html`. So you need to change it to `pub.cshtml_virtual.cshtml` or maybe shorten it to  `pub.cshtml`.

Comment: my file IS pub.cs.html, pub.cshtml_virtual.cshtml is file that contains errors or whatever

Comment: @JimmyOcha , just to clarify, the error you're trying to fix is `Unterminated string literal.`? That error is linked to the `pub.cshtml_virtual.html` file. You need to change the file extension to `.cshtml`.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so you need to understand the MVC architecture and how you want to implement different scenarios based on your requirement. Each `View` is rendered by its associated `Controller`. You can either a create a `View` without an associated `Model` and handle all your data on the `View` using front-end scripting technqiues such as `JavaScript` and `AJAX`.

Another technique which I prefer is `Model-View` bindining in which you would design the appropriate `Model` for your `View` and bind them using the `Controller`. Now based on your requirement, you can prepopulate your `Model` in your `Controller` and render your `View` with those values. Or you could use a strongly `Model` typed binding on your `View` to set your form data and then send it to associated method for processing using `Form` tag. Please note that this method will process your data and then return the appropriate `View`.

Now moving on to your case, the error that is being displayed is because of incorrect string literal in your action `onclick`. You may use this on your button event:

```
onclick="@("window.location.href='" + @Url.Action("Start", "Default") + "'");"
```

On the button click, you would be taken to `Start` action method of the `Default` controller.